# move forward by a certain number of chars or bytes?

Tags: unicode, navigation

Sometimes I need to move to a particular byte offset or move to the nth unicode rune in a file (utf-8).

Does vim expose a way to move to an absolute byte/char offset or to move the cursor forward a backward a given number of bytes/chars?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To go to the Nth byte in the file: use `:go N`, `:Ngo`, or `Ngo` (normal mode).

To move N bytes ahead, you could use something like this `:exe 'go' line2byte(line("."))+col(".")-1+N`

Unless you have changed `virtualedit`, you can move forward with `<space>`.  To go to the Nth character in the file, use `1goN<space>` in normal mode.

To move ahead N characters, use `N<space>` in normal mode.

Note: besides the obvious multi-byte character difference these also differ in that the first counts newlines and the second doesn't.

If you have `set virtualedit=all`, space won't work.  Instead you could use `/\%#\_.\{N}/e` for relative or `/\%1l\%1c\_.\{4}/e` for absolute.  Unlike the `<space>` version this counts end-of-lines.

Comment: I have `set virtualedit=all` active, which kind of messes with the operation of `space`. I'm looking for something that moves forward a certain number of characters (or bytes, as apporpriate) regardless of the value of any options.

Comment: See also https://superuser.com/questions/767504/how-to-go-to-the-nth-character-not-byte-of-a-file

Comment: +1: I was getting an error from a stupid parser that told me the input was malformed at "character number 1954," as if that's supposed to be helpful. This answer saved me!